# Why Delphi objects that implement interfaces need to be reference counted?

Tags: delphi, interface, com

In other words, why can't they be manually managed like a regular object? Or Did the Delphi designers just decided to use reference counting since it was needed for COM anyways?

Comment: Interfaces don't do anything. It's up to the classes implementing interfaces how they manage reference counting. Anyways, newer LLVM-based Delphi Compilers have introduced reference counting for object references also.

Comment: @GünthertheBeautiful That's true. But all Delphi interfaces derive from `IInterface`, and so assigning references leads to the compiler generating calls to `_AddRef` and `_Release`. The implementing object may do nothing, but the calls are still there. That's something that need not have been done, and is not baked into languages like C and C++.

Comment: Fact is that not the objects are reference counted, the interfaces are. The objects have to implement that part too, of course, but the calls to AddRef and Release are usually on the interfaces, not on the objects.

Answer (score 11):

The first thing to establish is that interfaces were added to Delphi to support COM. So a lot of the design decisions were driven by a desire to make COM programming easier.

Interface references could perfectly well be manually managed. In fact, raw COM in C and C++ did originally involve manual reference count management with explicit calls to `AddRef` and `Release`. When consuming COM objects from C you still need to perform manual reference count management. For C++ these days you typically use a class like `CComPtr` to enable automatic reference count management.

When COM support was being added to Delphi, the main competitor to Delphi was VB. And in VB you've never had to do manual reference count management. Had the Delphi designers not implemented automatic reference count management, it would have been much harder to woo VB programmers to leave VB and start using Delphi. So, I speculate that this was a driver in the decisions the Delphi designers made. Even were that not the case, it is much easier to code against automatic reference counting than to program it manually. So even if my speculation is wrong, the decision that the Delphi designers took makes life a lot simpler.

So to come to your specific questions:

> Why can't they be manually managed like a regular object?

They can be. You can implement `_AddRef` and `_Release` so that they do not control the lifetime of the object. Specifically, it is not compulsory for these methods to count references, nor for `_Release` to call `Free`.

> Did the Delphi designers just decide to use reference counting since it was needed for COM?

Well, it is not needed for COM. As I said above, you can code against COM in C or C++ (or indeed other languages) without automatic reference counting.

---

Another question that you might have asked, is why Delphi interfaces have to derive from `IInterface`. This stems from their original purpose, which was to implement COM interfaces. In many ways, it would be nice if we could have interfaces that did not derive from `IInterface`. But it is what it is.

Comment: Note that a Delphi object that derives from `TComponent` does have reference counting disabled, event if it implements any interfaces. And introducing a new non-refcounted interface type to the compiler has been requested many times before and Embarcadero is aware of it. Whether or not it will ever be implemented is anyone's guess.